# Tweepy occassional but persistent error "Expecting length, unexpected value found"

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've used Tweepy with the Twitter streaming API to put together a python script that collects tweets using a certain #hashtag and saves them to a database. I'm hosting it on its own Ubuntu server, which I log into from my computer via ssh.

I've been testing the code by tweeting myself, using the hashtag. When I start the script, it will stream the first one or two tweets, then on the next one, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stream.py", line 69, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=settings.TRACK_TERMS)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 450, in filter
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 364, in _start
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 297, in _run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 266, in _run
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py", line 323, in _read_loop
tweepy.error.TweepError: Expecting length, unexpected value found
```

Judging from my tests, this seems to have nothing to do with the length of the tweet, the position of the hashtag, or any special characters used in the tweet. Why does the script start working, process one or two tweets and add them to the database, and then suddenly come up with this error at the next tweet?

Below is my stream.py code (I have a separate file "settings.py" this refers to, which contains my track_term #hashtag and api keys):

```
import settings
import dataset
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob
from sqlalchemy.exc import ProgrammingError
import json

db = dataset.connect(settings.CONNECTION_STRING)

class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
        description = status.user.description
        text = status.text
        name = status.user.screen_name
        followers = status.user.followers_count
        created = status.created_at
        retweets = status.retweet_count
        id_str = status.id_str
        #creating and storing in database

        table = db[settings.TABLE_NAME]
        try:
            table.insert(dict(
                user_description=description,
                text=text,
                user_name=name,
                user_followers=followers,
                id_str=id_str,
                created=created,
                retweet_count=retweets,
            ))
        except ProgrammingError as err:
            print(err)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settings.TWITTER_APP_KEY, settings.TWITTER_APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(settings.TWITTER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(track=settings.TRACK_TERMS)
```

Comment: Haven't worked with Tweeps myself, but I guess I would start by adapting `build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/tweepy/streaming.py` by adding some print-statement(s) before line 323 to check which variables are expected, what kind of values are expected and to check what is actually getting through.. since there seems to be a mismatch there.. then, you can work your way back to find the fault.

Comment: I have the exact same error after updating from 3.4 to 3.5.

Comment: @SB87 thanks for the advice! That file seems to be something completely hidden from me and I'm not sure how to access it. Even when I set my file browser to "show hidden files". I can get to a file called streaming.py, but it doesn't seem to be the one I need. The egg is what is not accessible.

I ended up giving up on Tweepy and switching to the simplest possible way of calling the Twitter API and dumping the tweets into json. Now my problem is with a {hangup: True} error. Didn't realize the Twitter streaming API would be so difficult to work with.